# Switching between enabled and disabled ads, IDFA issue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ads

I'm working on an app that has two versions. A free version with advertisements, and a paid version without advertisements.

The only way I switch between the two is just a macro.

```
#ifdef kENALBED_ADS

  //ad call here

#endif
```

I disabled the ads, but I get this message...

**"Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage. Your app contains the Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage on the Prepare for Upload page in iTunes Connect."**

Do I have to make a new target and scheme where I don't use all the ad sdk's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your macro does not remove the API included into Xcode project, that references the AdSupport framework.

I got this problem solved by Removing below Ads SDK from Xcode target

```
1. Playhaven -> Removed from Xcode
2. Tapjoy    -> Removed from Xcode 
3. Aplovin   -> Used latest Aplovin SDK
```